# Proof exercise: finding hypothesis and conclusion in a statement

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am starting learn mathematical proofs and I was doing some exercise that needed to identify the hypothesis and the conclusion in a given statement. And I'm having trouble trying to figure it out in the following statement:

> The sum of the first $n$ positive integers is $n(n+1)/2$

what I could come up with is:

- hypothesis : Sum of first $n$ items is $n(n+1)/2$
- conclusion : $n$ items are positive integers

I get the feeling that this might be wrong so can a math wizard point me to the correct answer? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hypothesis: "$n$ is a positive integer"

Conclusion: "the sum $1+2+\cdots+n$ equals $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$"

and the given statement is: **if** hypothesis **then** conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you swapped it. The hypothesis is what you already know what is true. The conclusion is what you want to prove. Then:

- hypothesis: The $n$ items are the first $n$ positive integers.
- conclusion: Their sum is $n(n+1)/2$.